# jQuery .prev - can I get the instance before previous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, gridview

I have a jQuery 'each' function that loops through a gridview. Every time it encounters the right circumstances, it creates a new header and adds a css class to it:

```
$(this).before('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
$(this).prev().addClass('cd_header');
```

My problem is, I need to set some attributes of this header based on values in  elements of the last header I created. So a single .prev() doesn't work; it simply reads the attributes of the header I just created.

Is there some way of telling .prev that I want the one two instances back? Or can I stack .prev().prev() somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is assigning that injected html to an object and get prev of that. So you will get the two prev behind

```
var $row = $('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>')
$(this).before($row);
$row.prev().addClass('cd_header');
```

or shorter

```
$('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>').insertBefore($(this)).prev().addClass('cd_header');
```

Answer (score 2):

> Or can I stack .prev().prev() somehow?

Of course you can; you probably should have tried it. [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) returns the set of the immediately-preceding sibling of each element in the current set; no reason you can't then ask `prev` to do that a second time to go back one further.

Another option is `.prevAll('some-selector').first()` ([`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) followed by [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)), where `some-selector` is a selector that will identify the previous sibling you want to find. It finds *all* previous siblings matching the selector, and then takes the first of those (which is guaranteed by `prevAll` to be the one closest to where you started). That would be less brittle (e.g., if you changed things to insert *two* `tr`s instead of one at some point, it would keep working).

Comment: Well, I DID try it, but I kept getting an error. I'll keep working on my syntax. Thank you.